# Which/that in a justification

Tags: relative-pronouns

I hesitate between which and that after because:

> I prefer orange cars because blue cars would be thought of as the police(,) **which/that** is always aggressive.

Is it a restrictive/non-restrictive issue here?

Comment: That example... am I the only one it strikes as ungrammatical? _be though of __as__ the police_ works, but I'm trying to think of alternate intentions.

Comment: Not related to the main question, but "which/that is always aggressive." refers to the police? Or blue cars? My wondering is why its singular "is". *are* sounds better to me.

Comment: I think you mean basically: I prefer orange cars to blue cars, since blue cars can be mistaken for police cars and the police are always aggressive." ???

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

- The relative clause is non-restrictive clause, and only *wh-* forms may head non-restrictive relative clauses. Both *wh-* and *that* may head restrictive relative clauses. In restrictive clauses, but not non-restrictive clauses, the relativizer may be omitted if it does not stand for the subject of the relative clause (as it does in your example).
- At least in US usage, *the police* is considered a body of people and referred to with *who* rather *which*, so if you wish to say that the police are always aggressive you should use *who*.

  > I prefer orange cars because blue cars would be thought of as the police, who are always aggressive.

It may be, however, that what you are trying to say is that the use of *blue cars* arouses thoughts of aggressiveness, just as it arouses thoughts of the police. It is true that a *which* clause in this position leads the reader to think that the referent of *which*  is the entire preceding clause, *blue cars would be thought of as the police*. But it is not idiomatic English to say that this thought is *always aggressive*—that would mean that the thought was threatening to attack you! What you should say in this case is something more like

> I prefer orange cars because blue cars would be thought of as the police, which always suggests aggressiveness.

Answer (score 0):

'which' is used before non-restrictive clause whereas 'that' is used before restrictive clause. Restrictive clause forms unavoided part of the sentence which cannot be left off and non-restrictive clauses are avoidable clauses which cannot be peeled off the sentence. Here police which normally is considered aggressive makes clause 'always aggressive' non-mandatory so you can use 'which' in that senetence.

Comment: *Which* can be used in restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: *That which doesn't kill you makes you stronger.*  [Further discussion on Geoffrey Pullum's website.](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/relwhich.html)

Comment: Thank you @snailplane for bringing this to our attention